# Not getting EA notification with bluetooth

Tags: ios, external-accessory

I am able to get EA notification when connecting to an external device (MFi compliant) via USB but not via Bluetooth.  Why is EA notification not being fired for Bluetooth connection, contrary to what the documentation suggests?

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you set the Protocol String correctly in your InfoPlist? 
 2) Did you set the Protocol String correctly in your bluetooth device? 
 3) Did you register for incoming connection event? like this way:

```
-(void) <someMethod> {     
    [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(accessoryConnected:)
                                                 name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)accessoryConnected: (NSNotification *)notification {
    EAAccessory *accessory = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:EAAccessoryKey];
    NSLog(@"%@ connected", accessory.name);
}
```